# TypeError: this.setState is not a function with es6 function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I understand using bind.(this), and es6 fat arrow function (which is what im using), but it still returns this error message, and I cant figure out why. My code:

EDIT: added the rest of the class by request.

```
export default class Result extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data:''
        }
    }



    testAxios(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post('some api',
            {
                "Some-Data"
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Returned Data:', response.data);
                this.setState({ data: response.data });
                console.log('State data:', this.state.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }


    render() {
        return ()
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Can we see the full class?

Comment: Added full class. I get the data response fine, its the setting in state that's throwing the above type error. As far as I can tell, I am using this correctly in the es6 function.

Comment: Where are you calling `testAxios`?

Comment: Just a button in the return at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testAxios(e) {}` is not bound.

You have 2 options:

1. Bind this.testAxios to this in the constructor: 
   `this.testAxios = this.testAxios.bind(this);`
2. Use arrow function: `testAxios = (evt) => { ... }`

I suggest you to use arrow function for all custom methods in a class component.